# Fastest way to sample 1 pixel from the current screen

Tags: image, performance, screenshot

I am looking for the fastest way to get a pixel from the current screen. I am currently using python (I know, very slow) My code currently looks like this

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import pyautogui
while True:
    starttime = time.perf_counter()
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    coordinate = x, y = 1280, 720
    color = image.getpixel(coordinate)
    print(time.perf_counter() - starttime)
    print(color)
```

This typically takes about 0.06 seconds. Anyone have any ideas to speed this up? I would not be opposed to coding it in another language considering its a pretty simple program but any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You might mention your OS. You might mention if you only want to do it just once or actually repeatedly, and if so, for how long.

Comment: Im on windows and would like to do it repreatedly